# How can I replace all the query atoms at once with different functional groups in RDkit?

Tags: python, rdkit

I have a SMARTS string `'A-C-C(=O)-N'`, with a query atom A. If I want to replace A with OH group, the following code does the job:

```
repl = Chem.MolFromSmiles('O')
patt = Chem.MolFromSmarts('A')
m = Chem.MolFromSmarts('A-C-C(=O)-N')
rms = AllChem.ReplaceSubstructs(m,patt,repl)
rms[0]
```

Now let's say I have more than one query atoms, for example '`[A]-[C](=O)-C(-A)=C(-A)-[A]'`. I want to replace all four A's in here with a list of four different functional groups `[OH, Cl, NH2, Br]` respectively. My output should look like: `'O=C(O)C(Cl)=C(Br)N'`. Could anyone please help me solve this?
Thanks a lot!

[Image of Molecule represented by 'O=C(O)C(Cl)=C(Br)N'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUEVv.png)

Comment: Can you please provide the code how to create a substructure of "OH"? Because this is not working: `repl = Chem.MolFromSmiles('OH')` and `repl = Chem.MolFromSmiles('NH2')`

Comment: Hi, the code for creating substructures of OH and NH2 are `repl = Chem.MolFromSmiles('O')` and `repl = Chem.MolFromSmiles('N')`. But at first it doesn't make OH and NH2, instead it creates H2O and NH3 as the hydrogens gets added to fill the valencies. However, when we substitute these substructures on the main Smarts structure (in place of 'A') then they become OH and NH2 group (again, they organizes themselves as per the valencies).

Comment: Thanks, worked. So I tried with `ReplaceSubstructs` but also failed. Now I am thinking: Would it be possible to just edit the smile (the raw string) and then add back the hydrogens?

Comment: Did you figure this out yet? The [rdkit tag at MMSE](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rdkit) has 95.5% of its questions answered. If you want this question migrated there, please ping me by typing @Nike in a comment and letting me know. I'll make a case to the moderators for a migration.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the expected results using string manipulation of SMILES.

```
import re

string = '[A]-[C](=O)-C(-A)=C(-A)-[A]'
pattern = 'A'
len_of_ref_atom = len(pattern)
replacement_atoms = ['OH', 'Cl', 'NH2', 'Br']

start_end_positions_of_ref_atom = ([ match.start() for match in re.finditer(pattern, string)])

for start_pos_ref_atom, replacement_atom in zip(sorted(start_end_positions_of_ref_atom, reverse=True), replacement_atoms[::-1]):
  string = string[:start_pos_ref_atom] + replacement_atom + string[start_pos_ref_atom + len_of_ref_atom:]

print(string)
```

This displays :

```
[OH]-[C](=O)-C(-Cl)=C(-NH2)-[Br]
```